# android: graphical layout doesnt match emulator with same screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

When i hit emulate or use my app on a smartphone, it looks different from graphical layout editing, more specifically the height gets messed up

my graphical layout xml is like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1050dp"
        android:layout_height="1450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backright3" >
```

And I have about 100 TextViews in RelativeLayout.
Does anyone know what goes wrong when i emulate? it seems fine on edit mode.
It messes up the height, even when i use the same screen (edit mode/emulator)

(edit) pics:
on edit mode: http://s9.postimg.org/xlzho12yn/screen1.png
on emulator: http://s28.postimg.org/x826qezwt/screenemulator.png
(some textviews dont appear because i programmed it so)

Comment: Can u show images what happening ?

Comment: i think `100 TextViews in RelativeLayout` is bad idea. Use ListView instead.

Comment: I dont think ListView can help me.. i posted pics